# После переноса перестали загружаться картинки (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Перенос сайт с одного хостинга на другой, домен остался тот же. После переноса папки uploads картинки перестали загружаться. Даже если напрямую запросить картинку, открывается страница сайта. Сами картинки в папке присутствуют. В папке имеются картинки с русскими названиями. Подскажите что делать, перезаливать все заново слишком долго, там более 2 000 картинок + они по папкам распределены.

Comment: Гляньте какой адрес в базе записан к файлам, может там ошибки при переносе какие появились. Хотя и не должно было

Comment: @Moonvvell ошибок вроде бы нет. просто удивляет тот факт, что даже по прямой ссылке картинки недоступны. может быть как-то можно решить проблему с помощью .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так: изменил кодировку сайта (на UTF-8), в настройках фтп-менеджера (у меня FileZilla: открыть менеджер сайтов -> выбрать сайт -> кодировка -> UTF-8 принудительно) выставил кодировку utf-8, удалил старые файлы, загрузил файлы по новой. Далее заново восстановил бэкап БД и перезагрузил сайт (CTRL+R).